# trouble reading output of the board

Tags: arrays, c, syntax, symbols

This is my tic tac toe game.

The idea is simple, we just change it in the main function and it is reflected on the board, but I'm getting an answer that is basically an error even though the code works.

Output:

```
|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|

1|�|�|�|�|�|�|�|

2|�|�|�|�|�|�|�|

3|�|�|�|�|�|�|�|

4|�|�|�|�|�|�|�|

5|�|�|�|�|�|�|�|

6|�|�|�|�|�|�|�|

7|�|�|�|�|�|�|�|
```

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#ifndef __TRUE_FALSE__
#define __TRUE_FALSE__
#define True 1
#define False 0
#endif

#define ROWS 7
#define COLS 7
#define MARKONE "X"
#define MARKTWO "O"
#define Blank ".."

void InitializeBoard(char[ROWS][COLS]);
void DisplayBoard(char[ROWS][COLS]);    
int PlayerMove(int,int,char[ROWS][COLS],char);

int main(void) {
  char board[ROWS][COLS];

  InitializeBoard(board);

  PlayerMove(1,1,board, MARKONE);
  PlayerMove(1,2,board, MARKONE);
  PlayerMove(4,3,board, MARKONE);
  PlayerMove(1,1,board, MARKONE);
  PlayerMove(6,2,board, MARKTWO);
  PlayerMove(4,12,board, MARKTWO);
  
  DisplayBoard(board);

  return 0;
}

void InitializeBoard(char board[ROWS][COLS])  {
    for(int i=0; i<ROWS; i++)
      for(int j=0; j<COLS; j++)
        board[j][i] = Blank;
};
  
void DisplayBoard(char board[ROWS][COLS]) {
  printf(" |1|2|3|4|5|6|7|\n");

  for(int i = 0; i < COLS; ++i) {
    printf("%c|", '1' + i);

    for(int j = 0; j < ROWS; ++j) {
      printf("%c|", board[i][j]);
    }

    printf("\n");
  }

}

int PlayerMove(int row,int col,char board[ROWS][COLS], char symbol){
  if(board[row][col]!= Blank) {
    printf("That space is already occupied\n");
  }
  else if(row > ROWS) {
    printf("That move is not on the board\n");

  }
  else if(col > COLS) {
    printf("That move is not on the board\n");
  }
  else board[row][col] = symbol;
}
```

Comment: When I compile this code, I get about twenty compiler warnings about the type mismatch between the `char *` double-quoted strings where `char` is expected.  Did you not notice those?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using single quoted character literals:

'O', 'X' and '.' instead of the char* constants.

```
#define MARKONE 'X'
#define MARKTWO 'O'
#define Blank '.'
```

Comment: Thank you, I completely missed that. Your help is appreciated.